# group filed kendo grid with type object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have similar example to this grid 
http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/478/

I want to apply grouping on category field. I got an error. because category filed type is object. How can I specify the grouping filter field.

I tried this but it did not work

```
 groupable: {    
            field:"Category.CategoryName",
        }
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: Please any idea ? I have not solved this issue yet

Comment: I'm not sure if it's even possible to use grouping like this. I suggest you flatten the object to a new ViewModel which contains the CategoryName as a string property.

Comment: Rename the title from this issue to "kendo" instead of "keno".