# mix two toolbars in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid. I am using an add and custom button in the toolbar as the following code:

```
toolbar: ["create", {
            text: "Print record",
            className: "k-grid-custom",
            imageClass: "k-add"
        }],
```

I also want to add a custom toolbar (dropdown menu) as [this example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/toolbar-template.html)

I used similar code in the demo like

```
toolbar: kendo.template($("#toolbarIsExpire").html()),

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="toolbarIsExpire">
                <div class="toolbar">
                    <label  for="is_expired">Is Expired ?</label>
                    <input type="search" id="is_expired" style="width: 75px;"/>
                </div>
</script>
```

I want to show in the toolbar the add button and my custom button and the dropdown menu (IsExpired)

How to mix between the two toolbar in order to have both of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="toolbarIsExpire">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <label  for="is_expired">Is Expired ?</label>
        <input type="search" id="is_expired" style="width: 75px;"/>
    </div>
    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-add">  </span>Add new record</a>
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that before and I got an Error: Invalid template:'` Generated code:'var o,e=kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){o=' ...`

Comment: <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-add">  </span>Add new record</a>
I solved the error by adding 2 back slashes

Comment: can u help me with this question, I stuck there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547302/group-filed-keno-grid-with-type-object

Comment: sorry for the hash I copy pasted the line from html, yes it must be escaped as you correctly found out. I will have a look at the other question of yours in a bit.